# WPF No Build Actions for PNG image using VS 2015

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

[image]

Greetings,
On the following image you see that no `Build Actions` appears when I wanted to set its `build actions` to `Resources`.
Any ideas?

Comment: You need to include that in the project first. Right click on that file and choose include in project.

Comment: Aren't you the hero of the day. It solved my problem, thanks. 
How to convert this to an answer?

Comment: no need, glad to have helped solve the problem :)

Comment: Edited my "i" to "it", was a misspell :D 
As far as I'm aware, giving solutions have benefits for the helper, that's why I asked.